# Argument of type "tuple[str, str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__key" of type "tuple[Literal, Literal]"

Tags: python, pyright

I'm a python newbie and I have been solving Advent of Code questions with python. However, I encountered a problem when solving day 2's question.

I defined a `dict` that maps a `tuple` to a constant value. Specifically, I defined `score_table` to be:

```py
        score_table = {('A', 'X'): 3, ('A', 'Y'): 6, ('A', 'Z'): 0,
                       ('B', 'X'): 0, ('B', 'Y'): 3, ('B', 'Z'): 6,
                       ('C', 'X'): 6, ('C', 'Y'): 0, ('C', 'Z'): 3}
```

But later on, when I try to access the dict the following way, I received an error from pyright:

```py
        for line in f:
            u, v = line.split()
            ans = ans + score[v] + score_table[(u, v)]
```

The error says

```
Argument of type "tuple[str, str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__key" of type "tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['X']] | tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['Y']] | tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['Z']] | tuple[Literal['B'], Literal['X']] | tuple[Literal['B'], Literal['Y']] | tuple[Literal['B'], Literal['Z']] | tuple[Literal['C'], Literal['X']] | tuple[Literal['C'], Literal['Y']] | tuple[Literal['C'], Literal['Z']]" in function "__getitem__"
    Type "tuple[str, str]" cannot be assigned to type "tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['X']] | tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['Y']] | tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['Z']] | tuple[Literal['B'], Literal['X']] | tuple[Literal['B'], Literal['Y']] | tuple[Literal['B'], Literal['Z']] | tuple[Literal['C'], Literal['X']] | tuple[Literal['C'], Literal['Y']] | tuple[Literal['C'], Literal['Z']]"
      "tuple[str, str]" is incompatible with "tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['X']]"
        Tuple entry 1 is incorrect type
          "str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['A']"
      "tuple[str, str]" is incompatible with "tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['Y']]"
        Tuple entry 1 is incorrect type
          "str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['A']"
      "tuple[str, str]" is incompatible with "tuple[Literal['A'], Literal['Z']]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
1 error, 0 warnings, 0 informations 
Completed in 0.594sec
```

**However**, I was able to run the code, and even got the question correct. Is there something that I did wrong?

For reference, below is my entire program

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("day2.in", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        # A, X = rock, B, Y = paper, C, Z = scissors
        score = {'X': 1, 'Y': 2, 'Z': 3}
        score_table = {('A', 'X'): 3, ('A', 'Y'): 6, ('A', 'Z'): 0,
                       ('B', 'X'): 0, ('B', 'Y'): 3, ('B', 'Z'): 6,
                       ('C', 'X'): 6, ('C', 'Y'): 0, ('C', 'Z'): 3}
        ans = 0
        for line in f:
            u, v = line.split()
            ans = ans + score[v] + score_table[(u, v)]

        print(ans)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this looks like pyright's inference is a little too aggressive in this case, but you can probably help it by annotating the variables explicitly, so something like `score: dict[str, int] = ....` and `score_table = dict[tuple[str, str], int] = ....`

Comment: Feel free to answer and accept your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, pyright doesn't show any errors after I explicitly define the type of `score_table` in the following way:

```py
        score_table : dict[tuple[str, str], int] = {('A', 'X'): 3, ('A', 'Y'): 6, ('A', 'Z'): 0,
                       ('B', 'X'): 0, ('B', 'Y'): 3, ('B', 'Z'): 6,
                       ('C', 'X'): 6, ('C', 'Y'): 0, ('C', 'Z'): 3}
```